# In Python, use beautiful soup to pull data using list of div ID

Tags: arrays, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup, syntax

Have some Python experience. Very new to Beautiful soup.

I'm trying to take a list of div ID's for soup to find then export

What is the correct way to write this?

```
#my div ID list
DivIdList = [IdOne, IdTwo, IdThree,] 

#to be filled with soup 
ListName = [] 
HostList = []
InfoList = []

#loop through div ID list
for i in DivIdList:

    #when found fill up with soup
    Name = soup.find('IdOne')
    Host = soup.find('IdTwo')
    Info = soup.find('IdThree')

#Soup found to be exported
ListName.append(Name.text)
HostList.append(Host.text)
InfoList.append(Info.text)

#export soup info with headers
df = pd.DataFrame({'All Names':ListOfNames,....}) 
df.to_csv('MyFile.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `IdOne` etc are variables, you can use an f-string construct with `soup.select_one()`

```
soup.select_one(f'#{IdOne}')  # etc
```

The # denotes an id css selector.

You will use `i` to stand in as that is the loop variable; also, be consistent with variable naming `HostList`.

If `IdOne` is an id css selector already then remove the # and use direct e.g. `soup.select_one(i)`

You then need a way to add to the appropriate list e.g.

```
ListName = [] 
HostList = []
InfoList = []

list_of_lists = [ListName, HostList, InfoList]
DivIdList = [IdOne, IdTwo, IdThree]

for number, i in enumerate(DivIdList):
    list_of_lists[number].append(soup.select_one(f'#{i}').text)
```

It would be sensible to check `soup.select_one(f'#{i}') is not None` before using the `.text` accessor.

You could also have a dictionary, where the key is the id and the associated value, at start, is the relevant list to add to during the loop.

Comment: I like hash tables. Would the soup syntax change much from a normal has table in python to use soup? ```DivIdList= {'IdOne': 'ListName'}   print DivIdList[IdOne]```

Comment: Is there a reason for using lists when only grabbing a single item each time?

Comment: I'm importing a .csv list of asset names, asset names get plugged into the URL, and then pull info. I'm figuring it out as I go, not sure of the best method. Only have about a  year of python knowledge I'm working with.